# After adding namespace cannot get required output xml

Tags: xml, xslt

If I add namespace xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest" as

```
<?xml version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

in both usa11.xml and usa22.xml in my post:

[Updating info in one XML file with optional info from another, using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364771/updating-info-in-one-xml-file-with-optional-info-from-another-using-xslt)

Looks like that xslt cannot output expected results;
It works perfect without this xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest"

Pls help how to use XSL to fix it??

Thanks'

Comment: Perhaps you should start decide which answers to your previous questions are valid,  or tell why none.

Comment: An xmlns attribute in the XML declaration? Where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to refer to any elements in the XML data whose names belong to a namespace, you have to assign a *prefix* for that namespace in the stylesheet. Within the stylesheet, XSLT considers every element with an unprefixed name in an XPath expression or match pattern to have *no namespace*, even if there is a default `xmlns="http://..."` definition.

So you have to write something like

```
xmlns:app="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest"
```

and then prefix all references to nodes in your target XML data with the new namespace, like `app:root`.

I can't give a better example without seeing your live data. I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

To make the stylesheet from the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16366581/2115381) work, add the namespace declaration to the stylesheet (with a prefix) and use the new namespace prefix for all node names.

Therefore this should do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:y="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest"
                >

    <xsl:variable name="u2" select="document('usaa22.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="y:city">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$u2//y:city[y:street=current()/y:street]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$u2//y:city[y:street=current()/y:street]/* " />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() " />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() " />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Attention**: Your xml change seems not be correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The `<?xml` prologue does not allow a namespace.
The namespace should be added to the first element in your xml file:

```
<country xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/xmlns/ApplicationTest">
```

Comment: @LarsH: Thank you very much, for fixing and correcting my bad English.